# Wicket - login, back button, reload / rerender login page

Tags: button, authentication, wicket, reload, back

I have a Wicket (6.0) application. There is a LoginPage and a OverviewPage.
The LoginPage contains a form where a user can authenticate.
After authenticating, the user is redirected to the OverviewPage.

One special thing about the LoginPage is the following:

```
public void isUserLoggedIn() {

    if (getSession().isSignedIn()) {

        setResponsePage(new OverviewPage());

    }
}
```

If a user is correctly logged in and wants to go to the LoginPage, he will be automatically redirected to the OverviePage.

I tried this and entered the url in the browsers bar  `"http://anyserver/login/"`  and as i expected, i'll be redirected to the OverviewPage.

BUT, my problem is: If i logged in (LoginPage), i'll be redirected to the OverviewPage. If i press the browsers back button, i'll be redirected to the LoginPage?! But why? The direct url works like expected but the back-button not.

I also added things like:

```
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");
```

so there is a new request. I have checked it with FireBug.

But the logic of the LoginPage is only executed if someone enters the url. The back button doesnt do the logic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection logic is probably part of the constructor of the page (or the `onInitialize()`). The construction of the page is called if you come back on the page. Btw, you probably have the url for an instance of a page in your browser (you can see that by checking the presence of `'?n'` at the end of the url).
You can try putting this logic in the `onConfigure()` of the page. I didn't test this so I am not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the loginpage is the actual, previous page. setResponsePage sets up a new page's content as if your user clicked on an  link.

Wicket cached the contents of the page. If you use the back-button the browser asks for the exact, previous version of the page (indeed specified by the ? appended to the URL) so wicket delivers that.

If you want to send an actual redirect so this doesn't happen use

```
throw new RestartResponseException(OverviewPage.class);
```

or one of it's variants which let you create the page. You should also send this in the already-logged-in case.